# Django with django pipeline / Amazon s3 / Cloudfront : versioning assets

Tags: django, heroku, amazon-s3, assets, amazon-cloudfront

We recently moved to Heroku avec we decided to store our assets on Amazon S3 with a Cloudfront distribution.

I use Django Pipeline to compress / compile my assets but I didn't manage to make it points to the correct version.
When I run the "collectstatic" management command, it works well:

Post-processed 'css/compress_profile_school.css' as 'css/compress_profile_school.82973855aca5.css
Post-processed 'css/compress_profile.css' as 'css/compress_profile.d120536e24f9.css
Post-processed 'css/compress_document.css' as 'css/compress_document.864dd7603769.css
...

But when I run the app, it didn't point to the correct version (it uses the one with no hash).

The application is running here: http://dev.unishared.com/

It seems that the Django bundled staticfiles app can't point to the correct version too.

Each time I push new assets version, I have to invalidate my Cloudfront distribution which takes time..

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Can you add your STATIC_* and PIPELINE_* settings ?

Comment: Here it is:

class S3PipelineStorage(PipelineMixin, CachedFilesMixin, StaticStorage):
        pass



PIPELINE_STORAGE =     'UniShared_python.website.helpers.amazons3.S3PipelineStorage'
    STATICFILES_STORAGE =    'UniShared_python.website.helpers.amazons3.S3PipelineStorage'
    DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 's3_folder_storage.s3.DefaultStorage'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to cyberdelia I managed to make it works.

First, the "CachedFilesStorage" only put hashname in the filenames if your DEBUG settings is turned off (= False). 
It runs well on my production server.

From here, the "collectstatic" command is uploading the right files on S3 (with hash in the name). 
I met a second problem: the URL cached is pointing to the S3 Bucket but not the Cloudfront defined in the "STATIC_URL" setting.
I think it's related to django-storages / boto used by my custom storage which works with S3 and not Cloudfront:

```
class S3PipelineStorage(PipelineMixin, CachedFilesMixin, StaticStorage):
pass
```

(Static storage is a S3BotoStorage subclass with location sets to "static").

Now, I have to find a way to make it works properly with Cloudfront and not S3.

Thanks for your help!

**EDIT:**

I figured out to make it works via this post: [Django-compressor: how to write to S3, read from CloudFront?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8688815/django-compressor-how-to-write-to-s3-read-from-cloudfront)

While you define the "custom domain" key, it will use the Cloudfront domain instead of the Amazon S3.

I forgot to mention that I had to put the AWS_QUERYSTRING_AUTH to False to make it works.

Answer (score 1):

Don't setup `PIPELINE_STORAGE`, unless you really know what you are doing, just setup `STATICFILES_STORAGE`. See [storages documentation](http://django-pipeline.readthedocs.org/en/latest/storages.html#using-with-other-storages).

Comment: Hi,

At first I didn't set the PIPELINE_STORAGE variable. Next, I found it and try but didn't solved the problem.

The static used are always the non-versioned (without the hash in the name).

Thanks for your help

Comment: Do you run collectstatic on heroku ?

Comment: Also, what cache are you using, redis, memcached ?

Comment: I'm using memcached, via AWS Elasticache and yes I run collectstatic on Heroku (cf. my initial post, there is the output)

Answer (score 0):

Your situation may vary, but generally it's best to not serve this content with S3.

Excerpt from [whitenoise docs](http://whitenoise.evans.io/en/latest/index.html)

> Shouldn’t I be pushing my static files to S3 using something like
>   Django-Storages?
>
> No, you shouldn’t. The main problem with this
>   approach is that Amazon S3 cannot currently selectively serve gzipped
>   content to your users. Gzipping can make dramatic reductions in the
>   bandwidth required for your CSS and JavaScript. But while all browsers
>   in use today can decode gzipped content, your users may be behind
>   crappy corporate proxies or anti-virus scanners which don’t handle
>   gzipped content properly. Amazon S3 forces you to choose whether to
>   serve gzipped content to no-one (wasting bandwidth) or everyone
>   (running the risk of your site breaking for certain users).
>
> ...snip...
>
> The second problem with a push-based approach to handling static files
>   is that it adds complexity and fragility to your deployment process:
>   extra libraries specific to your storage backend, extra configuration
>   and authentication keys, and extra tasks that must be run at specific
>   points in the deployment in order for everything to work.

I use django-pipelines to join and minify my content at deploy time, whitenoise to serve static content, and Cloudfront CDN for caching.

I followed [this how-to](http://whitenoise.evans.io/en/latest/django.html) get it going.

It also means I'm only paying for CDN hits, not CDN + S3.