# Django CMS : Integrating CMS with CDN for faster delivery of static files

Tags: django, content-management-system, cdn, django-cms

Use-Case:

1. Need to upload an image which is bigger in size ( using django cms image plugin ) .
2. When I upload the image via CMS portal , where do the actual image is saved and in what format ?
3. Can I configure it to save in static folder of my source repo , so that I can push the new image to CDN ?

Also would like to know what is the standard practice for this use-case (image  ?

Comment: Uploaded images are uploaded to your `media_root` and served via your `media_url` settings. To serve them via a CDN you could use Amazon S3 for storage and Amazon Cloudfront (CDN) for distribution. Take a look at this answer for more details; https://stackoverflow.com/a/31440339/1199464