# Django and Django-CMS Static and Media URLs: https://https://

Tags: python, django, django-cms

In Django the following `settings` are configured:

```
MEDIA_URL="https://abcdefg.cloudfront.net/media/"
STATIC_URL="https://abcdefg.cloudfront.net/static/"
```

In web browsers the URL for the static files is correct.
The URL for media files however is incorrect with `https://https:` leading to `404`'s:
`https://https://abcdefg.cloudfront.net/media/`

When I `print(f"MEDIA_URL: {MEDIA_URL}")`, from the settings the URL is correct.
I use `{% get_media_prefix %}` and `{% get_static_prefix %}` for my static and media files. For example:

```
<img src="{% get_media_prefix %}image.jpg" alt="Image">
```

This alternative does not work:

```
MEDIA_URL="abcdefg.cloudfront.net/media/"
```

The result observed in the browser is `https://example.com/abcdefg.cloudfront.net/media/`

**EDIT:** Am using Django-CMS. Only the URLs for Django-CMS seem to show the above behavior.

What is the issue here?

Comment: maybe this can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5517950/django-media-url-and-media-root

Comment: Thanks. No, that is a different issue

Comment: What you're doing looks correct. And django-cms doesn't override these parts of django. The functionality here is core django. This seems a solid article on the matter, maybe give it a read and verify your setup, though I don't think it'll sort the protocol duplication, it may help. https://www.laurencegellert.com/2018/03/django-correctly-wiring-to-aws-cloudfront-for-static-and-media-files/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution:**
Triggered by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31357353/using-cloudfront-with-django-s3boto), I figured out based on the `django-storages` [documentation](https://django-storages.readthedocs.io/en/latest/backends/amazon-S3.html), that specifically for Django-CMS, when using `CloudFront` I had to add `AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN` to my settings. The format is different, however:

```
STATIC_URL="https://abcdefg.cloudfront.net/static/"
MEDIA_URL="https://abcdefg.cloudfront.net/media/"
AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN="abcdefg.cloudfront.net"
```