# Django: ImageField - Upload to S3 but read from cloudfront?

Tags: python, django, amazon-s3, boto, amazon-cloudfront

I have configured my django app's default file storage to use `boto`.

```
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto.S3BotoStorage
```

I also have a model that stores uploaded images to s3

```
...
profile_pic = models.ImageField(upload_to=get_upload_path, null=True)
...
```

However, when I reference this field, it shows up with an S3 url. 
How do I configure this to return a cloudfront address?

Comment: This may be useful http://stackoverflow.com/a/8888930/263989

Answer (score 0):

Use `AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN` in Djangp Storage there is option to specify CloudFront URL